# My condition not working my app crashes as button click

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I am trying to check if the EidtText is empty or not. Variable for EditText is in float type.

```
float interObtain = Float.valueOf(editText1.getText().toString());
if (interObtain == 0 ) {
  editText1.setError("Please Fill this Field");
}
```

---

```
07-31 12:04:16.363 26780-26780/com.example.iubmeritcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.iubmeritcalculator, PID: 26780
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63) at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:308) at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306) at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:343) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5052)at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20162) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5753) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:145) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Comment: *java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""* Isn`t this message clear? if the field is empty you get an empty string which is not a souble

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to parse an empty string into a Float, which fails.

If you want to check for an empty value, 0 value or invalid formatted values you could try:

```
   if (editText1.getText().isEmpty()) {
     editText1.setError("Please Fill this Field");
   } else {
     try{
       float interObtain = Float.valueOf(editText1.getText());
       if (interObtain == 0 ) {
         editText1.setError("Value should be different from 0");
       }
     } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
       editText1.setError("Value has an invalid format");
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isEditTextEmpty(EditText editText) {
    return editText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
}
```

This is a method you could implement which returns true, if the editText is empty, it`s better than checking the float value.

Answer (score 0):

editText1.getText().toString()  is return "" value when edittext is empty or it can't converted in float number so it's giveing error

you can check with this code

```
if(editText1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""){
// show your error here
}
```